# If $A$ is $m\times n,$ prove that every vector in $null(A)$ is orthogonal to every vector in $row (A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have no idea where to begin with question. Can someone please give me an idea of where to start or walk me through this please?

Comment: Start with the definition of the null space, and think about how matrix multiplication and dot products of rows / columns are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $v\in null(A)$ then by definition we have $Av=0$. How is matrix multiplication defined? If the rows of $A$ are $r_i=(a_{i1}\enspace a_{i2} \enspace \cdots \enspace a_{in})$ for $1\leq i \leq m$ and 
$v=\begin{pmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2\\
\vdots\\
v_n
\end{pmatrix}$. Then $$0=Av=\begin{pmatrix} 
r_1 \cdot v\\
r_2 \cdot v \\
\vdots \\
r_m \cdot v
 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $"\cdot"$ denotes the dot-product. If one prefers, one can write the $i^{th}$ entry as $r_i^Tv$ if we regard $r_i$ as a column vector.
But this says exactly that each row of $A$ is orthogonal to $v$, and since the rows of $A$ generate $row(A)$, and the choice of $v\in null(A)$ was arbitrary we have the desired result.