# Kernel is perpendicular to column space for a normal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

For a normal matrix $M^*M = MM^*$ where $M^*$ is the conjugate transpose, how do I show that any vector in the kernel of $M$ is perpendicular to the column space of $M$?

I know that any vector in the kernel is perpendicular to the row space [If $A$ is $m\times n,$ prove that every vector in $null(A)$ is orthogonal to every vector in $row (A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671777/if-a-is-m-times-n-prove-that-every-vector-in-nulla-is-orthogonal-to-eve) so maybe one way to approach this is to show that the column space of a normal matrix is equal to its row space.

Comment: Are you sure your statement is correct? The identity matrix $I_n$ is normal, but the column space and row space are both $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I guess my approach is wrong, but the statement might still be correct. In the case of $I_n$ the kernel is the $0$ matrix which is orthogonal to its image.

Comment: But your claim is that vectors of the rowspace (not the kernel) are orthogonal to the image.

Comment: @angryavian Ohh that' a typo, I'm really sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in \text{nullspace}(M)$. By definition $Mx=0$, but normality also implies $M^* x = 0$:
$$\|M^* x\|^2 = (M^* x)^* (M^* x) = x^* M M^* x = x^* M^* M x = \|Mx\|^2 = 0.$$

Let $My \in \text{colspace}(M)$. Using the fact that $M^* x = 0$, we have
$$x^* (My) = (M^* x)^* y = 0.$$